# Strange behaviour in constant method where variable can be modified

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, constants

I am using a gcc compiler for the following piece of code:

```
base operator +(  base& b)const
{
        int i=12;  // local variable
        i++;       // works fine

        base temp;
        b=temp;     // works fine
        temp.x=x+b.x;
        return(temp);   
}
```

I am getting a strange behavior for the constant function. I am able to modify only the local variable and the argument. Since the method is a constant, I am wondering how can any modification happen inside the function body?

Someone please explain this behavior.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot your question in your question.

Comment: What does this const do? The object where operator+ is called can´t be changed by it. => Is `b` the object where you call `+`? No.

Comment: Well since this is not a hard question to answer with some basic googling, I'm not going to vote to re-open. However, I'll answer it briefly; `const` can be put many places. Where you have it simply means *The object on which this method is operating cannot be modified*. Since `int i` and `base temp` are both local non-const variables, they do not belong to the object and thus can be modified freely.

Comment: yes b is the object which is calling operator

Comment: @user3227126 Where? I don´t see this. Even if, the compiler doesn´t have to check parameters (it can´t reliably check them, anyway. Pointers...)

Comment: hope you mean to say that only the calling object cannot be changed inside constant method ie b1+b2 ,b1 is calling object only b1 cannot be modified ,we can modify b2.Hope i right

Comment: @user3227126 Yes, exactly-

Comment: the `const` keyword cannot be applied to normal functions. Are you sure you are talking about a method?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Since the method is a constant, how can any modification happen inside the function body?

When a member functions is a `const` member function, you cannot modify the object on which the function is called. You can modify other modifiable objects.

In your function, you cannot do this:

```
this->x = x+b.x; // Not allowed.
x = x+b.x;       // Not allowed either.
```

Answer (score 0):

The const member method only can not modify the member variable